# HTML/Django/Jinja/Python : How to post a fixed value back

Tags: python, html, django

This is a HTML template that displays all of the proposals in a database (passed through views.py as a list in the dictionary parameter). I then use a jinja for-loop to go through all the proposals in the database and display their attributes.

How can I Post-request the {{ proposal.id }} back to my python code when the "Learn more" button is clicked? I need this to allow me to display the corresponding values in my other html template.

Sorry if this is a basic question, i'm a high school student and extremely new to django! Thanks alot in advance!

```
{% block body %}
    {% for proposal in proposals %}
    <div class="jumbotron">

     <h2> Proposal :  {{ proposal.title }} </h2>
     <h4> Status : {{ proposal.status }} </h4>
     <h4> Out of --- Votes: </h4>
      <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: {{ proposal.votes_for }}%">
            <span class="sr-only">35% Complete (success)</span>
            {{ proposal.votes_for }}% For
          </div>
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger"  style="width: {{ proposal.votes_against }}%">
            <span class="sr-only">10% Complete (danger)</span>
            {{ proposal.votes_against }}% Against
          </div>
      </div>

      <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to go to the `Proposal` details you should definitely look to a class-based [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/).

You can make it with `AJAX` request or you can make it with form. For the both of types you should have a `View` to catch it.

**HTML Form:**

In your template you should have:

```
<form id="formId" method="post" action="{% url 'catch-proposal' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="proposal_id" value="{{ proposal.id }}"/>
    <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more</a></p>
    <!-- <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Learn more"/> -->
</form>
```

It will go to your `View` from `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^post/for/proposal/$', catch_proposal, name='catch-proposal'),
# if your view class-based
# url(r'^post/for/proposal/$', CatchProposal.as_view(), name='catch-proposal')
```

Then in your view you will catch POST data:

```
def catch_proposal(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST) # have a look for your post params
    return reverse_lazy('index') # your response, you can make it on your own
```

**AJAX:**

Check it! [AJAX and Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie)

> **Page uses AJAX without any HTML form**
>
> A page makes a POST request via AJAX, and the page does not have an HTML form with a csrf_token that would cause the required CSRF cookie to be sent.
>
> Solution: use ensure_csrf_cookie() on the view that sends the page.

In your scripts define:

```
function sendPost(proposalId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url 'catch-proposal' %}', // or just /ajax/catch/proposal/
        method : "POST",
        data: {
            // your data to send key => val
            'id': proposalId
        },
        dataType: 'json', // it can be xml, json, script, html
        success: function (result) {
            // Do something if your request was successful (code=200)
            // All response data stored in result
            console.log(result)
        },
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            // Error case
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

For your `Learn More` button:

```
<p><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button" onclick="sendPost({{ proposal.id }})">Learn more</button></p>
```

And you will catch it in your `View`:

```
@ensure_csrf_cookie # Since you sending POST request without form tag
def catch_proposal(request):
    response_data = {} # your response
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # your post request
        if 'id' not in request.POST: # check the param from POST
            # Provide error message
            response_data['error_message'] = "Can't find ID in POST params..."
        else:
            # Do whatever
            proposal_id = int(request.POST.get('id'))
            try:
                proposal = Proposal.objects.get(id=transport_id)
                response_data['success'] = True
            except Proposal.DoesNotExist:
                response_data['success'] = False
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
    else:
        response_data = {
            'error_message': 'Something is going very strange and wrong...'
        }
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

Adding created `View` to `urls.py`:

```
from .views import catch_proposal # or yourapp.views
....
url(r'^ajax/catch/proposal/$', catch_proposal, name='catch_proposal'),
....
```